# How to implement TabLayout.IOnTabSelectedListener.OnTabUnselected with TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom" - Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I just recently used `android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"`. I used to have the following code:

```
void TabLayout.IOnTabSelectedListener.OnTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
{
   var playPage = Element.CurrentPage as NavigationPage;
   if (!(playPage.RootPage is PhrasesFrame))
      return;

   var tabLayout = (TabLayout)ViewGroup.GetChildAt(1);
   var playTab = tabLayout.GetTabAt(4);
   tab.SetText("Play");
   tab.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.ionicons_2_0_1_play_outline_25);
   App.pauseCard = true;
}
```

Anyone knows how can I implement this with `ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"` ? I have implemented both `BottomNavigationView.IOnNavigationItemSelectedListener`, `BottomNavigationView.IOnNavigationItemReselectedListener` but can't find any reference for `UnselectedTab` if there is any.

**Edit:**

Previous custom renderer using the default tab position and implementing `TabLayout`:

```
namespace Japanese.Droid
{
    public class MyTabbedPageRenderer: TabbedPageRenderer, TabLayout.IOnTabSelectedListener
    {
        ViewPager viewPager;
        TabLayout tabLayout;
        bool setup;

        public MyTabbedPageRenderer(Context context): base(context){ }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // More codes here
        }

        void TabLayout.IOnTabSelectedListener.OnTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
        {
            UpdateTab(tab);
        }

        void TabLayout.IOnTabSelectedListener.OnTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
        {
            UpdateTab(tab);
        }

        void TabLayout.IOnTabSelectedListener.OnTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
        {
            var playPage = Element.CurrentPage as NavigationPage;
            if (!(playPage.RootPage is PhrasesFrame))
                return;

            var tabLayout = (TabLayout)ViewGroup.GetChildAt(1);
            var playTab = tabLayout.GetTabAt(4);
            tab.SetText("Play");
            tab.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.ionicons_2_0_1_play_outline_25);
            App.pauseCard = true;
        }

        void UpdateTab(TabLayout.Tab tab) 
        {
            // To have the logic only on he tab on position 1
            if (tab == null || tab.Position != 4)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (tab.Text == "Play")
            {
                tab.SetText("Pause");
                tab.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.ionicons_2_0_1_pause_outline_22);
                App.pauseCard = false;
            }
            else
            {
                tab.SetText("Play");
                tab.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.ionicons_2_0_1_play_outline_25);
                App.pauseCard = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Current custom renderer using the `ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"`:

```
namespace Japanese.Droid
{
    public class BottomTabPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer, BottomNavigationView.IOnNavigationItemSelectedListener, BottomNavigationView.IOnNavigationItemReselectedListener
    {
        public BottomTabPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TabbedPage> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            // More codes here
        }

        bool BottomNavigationView.IOnNavigationItemSelectedListener.OnNavigationItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            base.OnNavigationItemSelected(item);

            UpdateTab(item)
        }

        void BottomNavigationView.IOnNavigationItemReselectedListener.OnNavigationItemReselected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            UpdateTab(item);
        }

        void UpdateTab(IMenuItem item)
        {
            var playTabId = 4;

            var title = item.TitleFormatted.ToString();
            if (item == null || item.ItemId != playTabId)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (item.ItemId == playTabId)
            {
                if (title == "Play")
                {
                    item.SetTitle("Pause");
                    item.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.ionicons_2_0_1_pause_outline_22);
                    App.pauseCard = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    item.SetTitle("Play");
                    item.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.ionicons_2_0_1_play_outline_25);
                    App.pauseCard = true;
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

So now my problem is I don't have any idea how will I implement the `TabLayout.IOnTabSelectedListener.OnTabUnselected` in the new custom renderer.

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more. I don't get what you mean.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT sorry for the confusion. I am using ToolbarPlacement="Bottom" now for my Xamarin.Forms Android app. Before when using the default placement of tabbar in android i used to extend `TabLayout.IOnTabSelectedListener` to handle events such as `OnTabReselected`, `OnTabSelected`, and `OnTabUnselected`. Now I dont know how to handle `OnTabUnselected` with BottomNavigationView. Does that makes sense?

Comment: @SamanthaJTStar - Are you people interested to use custom renderer?

Comment: @Arvindraja I am using custom renderer. Please see the edits above

Comment: So are you looking for the unselected event in bottom navigation view?

Comment: @G.hakim that is correct

Comment: BottomNavigationView does not have an unselected event but what you can do is you can keep a variable that captures which was the last selected menu item and then use that to determine which one got unselected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per G.Hakim's suggestion, I was able to do what I wanted to do by capturing the tab item I wanted to work on and do the necessary actions in `BottomNavigationView.IOnNavigationItemSelectedListener.OnNavigationItemSelected`.

```
namespace Japanese.Droid
{
    public class BottomTabPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer, BottomNavigationView.IOnNavigationItemSelectedListener, BottomNavigationView.IOnNavigationItemReselectedListener
    {
        // same as above

        bool BottomNavigationView.IOnNavigationItemSelectedListener.OnNavigationItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            base.OnNavigationItemSelected(item);

            if(item.ItemId == 4 && item.TitleFormatted.ToString() == "Play") 
            {
                item.SetTitle("Pause");
                item.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.ionicons_2_0_1_pause_outline_22);
                App.pauseCard = false;
                playTab = item;
            } 

            if(item.ItemId !=4 && playTab.TitleFormatted.ToString() == "Pause") 
            {
                playTab.SetTitle("Play");
                playTab.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.ionicons_2_0_1_play_outline_25);
                App.pauseCard = true;
            }
            return true;
        }

        // same as above

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no official stuff for `OnTabReselected` event for `TabbedPage`'s bottom navigation or 
`BottomNavigationView` because It doesn't use `TabLayout.Tab` for a start. Many overridden methods of `TabbedPageRenderer` not being called like `SetTabIcon`. If you are using `IOnTabSelectedListener` interface(As your first part of code) you have three methods to use.

```
void OnTabReselected(Tab tab);
void OnTabSelected(Tab tab);          
void OnTabUnselected(Tab tab);
```

But when it comes to `BottomNavigationView` interface you have only two methods

```
void OnNavigationItemReselected
bool OnNavigationItemSelected
```

So we don't have built in `OnTabUnselected` method. Here you need to write custom code to make unseleted event.

I have tried this code without using custom renderer using 4 tabs pages & the xaml of tabbed written in MailPage.xaml file. First declare `List<string>` in `App.xaml.cs` file to store `Title` of all tabs

```
public static List<string> Titles {get;set;}
```

Add tabs pages title in above list from `MainPage.xaml.cs` file's `OnAppearing` method

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this.Children.Count; i++)
    {
        App.Titles.Add(this.Children[i].Title);
    }
}
```

Now go to your `MyTabbedPage` class in which is available in shared project.

```
public class MyTabbedPage : Xamarin.Forms.TabbedPage
{
    string selectedTab = string.Empty;
    string unSelectedTab = string.Empty;
    bool isValid;

    public MyTabbedPage()
    {
        On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().SetToolbarPlacement(ToolbarPlacement.Bottom);

        this.CurrentPageChanged += delegate
        {
            unSelectedTab = selectedTab;
            selectedTab = CurrentPage.Title;
            if (App.Titles != null)
                isValid = true;
            else
                App.Titles = new List<string>();
            if (isValid)
            {
                MoveTitles(selectedTab);
               //Pass 0 index for tab selected & 1 for tab unselected
                var unSelecteTabTitle = App.Titles[1];
               //TabEvents(1); here you know which tab unseleted call any method
            }
        };
    }

    //This method is for to moving selected title on top of App.Titles list & unseleted tab title automatic shifts at index 1
    void MoveTitles(string selected)
    {
        var holdTitles = App.Titles;
        if (holdTitles.Count > 0)
        {
            int indexSel = holdTitles.FindIndex(x => x.StartsWith(selected));
            holdTitles.RemoveAt(indexSel);
            holdTitles.Insert(0, selected);
        }
        App.Titles = holdTitles;
    }    

}
```

Or you can make swith case like this

```
void TabEvents(int index)
{
  switch (index)
  {
    case 0:
        //Tab selected
        break;
    case 1:
         //Tab unselected
        break;
  }
}
```

Few things I should mention that `MainPage.xaml.cs` file inheriting `MyTabbedPage`

```
public partial class MainPage : MyTabbedPage
```

Structure of MainPage.xaml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<local:MyTabbedPage   

    <TabbedPage.Children>

        <NavigationPage Title="Browse">     
        </NavigationPage>   

    </TabbedPage.Children>
</local:MyTabbedPage>
```

Answer seems long but hope it help you.